# addEventListener function not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to check if a function that is meant to be triggered by a click with a console.log but the console message never comes up

```
<script src="e-com.js" async></script>
```

this is how i linked the js file in the head

```
<a href="" id="remove">Remove</a>
```

this is the link I want the event on

```
let removeItem=document.getElementById("remove")
for (i=0; i<removeItem.length; i++){
let  remove = removeItem.addEventListener("click", function(){

  console.log("Clicked");
  })
}
```

This is the js function

Comment: Your debugger/console is your friend. Hint: What is `removeItem.length`?

Comment: Why are you trying to loop over the result of `getElementById`? It only returns one item. Did you mean to use `querySelectorAll`? If so, why do you have multiple elements with the same `id` on the page?

Comment: This is the opposite of the usual problem, where people call `getElementsByClassName` and don't loop over the results. `getElementById` doesn't return a list, you don't need a loop.

Comment: It is supposed to be a remove button for a cart e-commerce page so it would only remove one item if there were more of the same selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you are trying to loop over the result of `getElementById()`, which doesn't return an iterable.

---

To fix it, you just need to remove the loop. The code below should work correctly<sup>^</sup>.

```js
const removeItem = document.getElementById("remove");

removeItem.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

```html
<a href="" id="remove">Remove</a>
```

According to [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method **`getElementById()`** returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object representing the element whose [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) property matches the specified string.

As it states, `getElementById()` returns an `Element`, which is just an object, in short. This is why you cannot iterate over it.

---

If you wanted to listen to multiple objects with a `for` loop, you need to change a few things.

First, you can't use an `id`, as the `id` attribute is unique, and can only be used once in a HTML document. Therefore, to get multiple elements, you need to use the `class` attribute. See an example of the `class` attribute in use below.

```html
<div class="division">Division!</div>
```

The `class` attribute can be used by any HTML element.

So, to get all of the classes and iterate over them, you need to use either the [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method, or the [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

The only difference between the two is that `getElementsByClassName()` returns a **live** `HTMLCollection`, while `querySelectorAll()` returns a **static** `HTMLCollection`.

If you were to use `querySelectorAll()`, your code would look like this<sup>^</sup>.

```js
const removeItem = document.querySelectorAll("remove");

Array.from(removeItem).forEach((ele) => {
  ele.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("Clicked!");
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="" class="remove">Remove</a>
<a href="" class="remove">Remove</a>
<a href="" class="remove">Remove</a>
```

---

Both of these solutions should work correctly, but they depend on what you need to accomplish.

---

*<sup>^</sup> The code has been modified slightly.*

Answer (score 0):

.getElementById() doesn't return an array since you're not allowed to have more than one element with a single id.

Therefore, the for loop failed.

Try

```
let removeItem=document.getElementById("remove")

removeItem.addEventListener("click", function(){

  console.log("Clicked");
})
```